# Okta: Fetching Access Token via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, okta-api

I've been struggling to really understand the Okta docs regarding this but basically im trying to fetch an Okta Access Token via their API using Vanilla JS.

I am using the following JS SDK to simplify things:
https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js

this is my code:

```js
let oktaConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://{OKTA_DOMAIN}/oauth2/default/v1/token',
  clientId: "CLIENT_ID",
  tokenManager: {
    storage: 'sessionStorage'
  }
}

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig)

oktaAuth.signInWithCredentials({
  username: "USER", 
  password: "PASSWORD"
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)

  let token = data.data.stateToken
  console.log(token)
```

From the request I retrieve a "stateToken" however how am I able to then retrieve a Access Token?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the account had been setup with MFA enabled and therefore I was only getting the "stateToken". By disabling MFA on the account I receive a "sessionToken" which can be parsed into the /authorize endpoint to retrieve the Access Token